Can't access to the website and admin's website using wordpress CMS after trying to access to cpanel (https://mydomainname/cpanel) fail
Iam having a problem that i can't access to my website after fail trying to login to the cpanel using this url like that(https://mydonainname/cpanel). I need to custom the content in my wordpress website from the admin page. But there are some problem made me can't add new plugin, the add new plugin page being not found. So i try to access to the cpanel to check the problem using my admin page account to login to the cpanel but i can't login to cpanel. After that, i try to access to my website and the admin page but it's not work. Can anyone help me.
What can i do to fix the problem to access to my website again.

It's sounds like you have problem with your hosting server First, confirm whether your website is down for everyone or just for you. You can use an online service like Down For Everyone Or Just Me to check this.
Clear your browser cache or try with incognito window, better try with alternative internet connections if issue still then Access cPanel Directly
If your usual cPanel login URL isn't working, try accessing cPanel directly through your hosting provider's website. Most hosting providers have a portal where you can log in and access your cPanel from there.
